# Vincent graph won't display in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, vincent

I have Anaconda with Python 2.7 and am trying to use Vincent.  I did pip install and that seemed to work.  I tried to run it in Spyder and separately in iPython, but neither seemed to work.  I tried this in iPython:

```
import vincent
import pandas as pd
vincent.core.initialize_notebook()
X= [
 [0,0,1,1,1,0],
 [1,1,0,0,0,1],
 [1,0,0,0,1,1],
 [0,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,1,0],
 [1,1,0,0,0,1]
 ]
x1 = pd.DataFrame(X)
line = vincent.Line(x1)
line.display()
```

I got the following error:

```
Javascript error adding output!
TypeError: Object doesn't support this action
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

I then tried running it in Spyder.  It created the line object, but didn't display anything.  When I type

```
type(line)
```

I get

```
<class 'vincent.charts.Line'>
```

Which is good, but I want to show the line!  Am I missing a dependency, or is my syntax off?

Comment: It seems like I'm close, but I just can't figure out how to display the data.